# Error on Update inventory REST API? when SKU has a "#" in it

Tags: api, rest-api, inventory

I'm trying to update the inventory of our products from our ERP using the rest api.  I have run into an issue when the SKU has a pound "#" in it.

A URL like:

https://magento.xyx.com/rest/V1/products/3736924F5/stockItems/1

works fine but a URL of:

https://magento.xyx.com/rest/V1/products/3736924F5#M/stockItems/1

Returns the error:

(
    [message] => "%fieldName" is required. Enter and try again.
    [parameters] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fieldName] => product
        )

)

I tried to URL encode the SKU but that didn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like my only option is to update the database directly and the clear some cache.  Does anyone know what cache I need to clear to display the new quantity?  I cleared all of the caches and it works but I don't know which one(s) in particular I should clear.

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

as usual sku's dont contain special charactes like "#". A SKU is build by the following parameters:

- Can be any length
- Alphanumeric
- Created by retailers

[image: Sku build up]

**SKU Number Example for a Convenience Store**
[image: SKU exmaple]
In the sample above, notice that the first two numbers represent each category of goods in the convenience store. The next four numbers are a sequential numbering system. As long as you don’t have more than 99 departments, or over 9999 products in a given department, this system works and is simple to enter and maintain in any POS system.
However, if you want a SKU number to convey more information about each item, a different system with more identifiers is needed.

---

**Heres a good article about SKU's and how they work:**

https://fitsmallbusiness.com/sku-numbers/

Comment: We are using SKUs from our ERP and they do contain special characters.  I guess there dis no work around unless I dive into the API code.  Not really something I wan't to do.